# Как через VK API получить id группы по URL?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Как через VK API получить идентификатор группы по её URL?

Answer (score 4):

Существует определенный метод - [`utils.resolveScreenName`](https://vk.com/dev/utils.resolveScreenName), для определения типа объекта (как пользователя, так и сообщества) и вывода его идентификатора по короткому имени.